# how Calculate Margin in GP

Tags: dynamics-gp

I want to Calculate profit margin from Dynamics GP Database.
Which fields or table been used. and How Can I do that.

If any one have an idea please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are many different ways to calculate gross profit margin. Be sure you are using the method which is accepted by your companies accounting policies.

Here is an example which looks at all invoices which have been posted year to date and calculates the gross profit margin percentage.

Assuming gross profit margin = total profit / total revenue.

```
SELECT ( SUM(SUBTOTAL) - SUM(EXTDCOST) ) / SUM(SUBTOTAL)
FROM   SOP30200 t1
WHERE  t1.SOPTYPE = 3
       AND t1.DOCDATE BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND GETDATE()
```

This will return a decimal number like .44323. In that case you would be making an average gross profit margin of 44% for every invoice year to date.

SOP30200 = posted sales transaction documents